# What is a efpt.config.json file and should it be checked into source control?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, version-control, entity-framework-core

I am using Visual Studio and EF Core Power Tools to reverse engineer some models from my database. This creates a `efpt.config.json` in my directory and I am wondering whether or not this is something that should be checked into source control for my project.

```
{
    "ContextClassName": "MyContext",
    "DefaultDacpacSchema": null,
    "IdReplace": false,
    "IncludeConnectionString": false,
    "OutputPath": "",
    "ProjectRootNamespace": "My.Name.Space",
    "SelectedToBeGenerated": 0,
    "Tables": [
        ...
    ],
    "UseDatabaseNames": true,
    "UseFluentApiOnly": true,
    "UseHandleBars": false,
    "UseInflector": false
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am the creator of EF Core Power Tools, and I recommend that you check in this file with your project, doing that ensures that all developers use the same option when running the Reverse Engineer wizard

Comment: .. unless you have more than 1 dbcontexts in the project? Since it would then just keep on changing depending on which dbcontext you updated last.

Comment: Maybe it i not a good idea to mix multiple DbContexts in the same project?

Comment: That is debatable and not in the scope of this Q. The fact that the tool is currently limited in this regard, is. Just saying that you could improve your answer with this information.

Comment: Thank you!  That JSON file is very nice.  It saves a lot of time with documentation.

Comment: Re multiple db contexts see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860851/how-to-manage-multiple-dbcontext-in-same-project-with-ef-core-power-tools

Comment: It's not a big issue but in our team the efpt.config.json occasionally causes merge conflicts because of changes to the list of Tables, and more often because of the UiHint - this changes to include the machine name of whichever developer last used the Reverse Engineer wizard. Has anyone run into the same issue and managed to find a workaround?

Comment: @dave there is an option in Tools/Options to not Save the uihint

Comment: We are also seeing differences in the OnModelCreating partial in the DbContext, for some team members it preserves the `modelBuilder.UseCollation("Latin1_General_CI_AS");` we had before we started using Power Tools whereas for other team members it removes it. We are all using the same efpt.config.json in source control and I can't see any Power Tools settings that would change this.

Comment: @Dave please create an issue on Github and I will investigate

Comment: No problems, I will check the version everyone is using and then create the issue.