# How to manage multiple dbcontext in same project with EF Core Power Tools?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I need to manage multiple context in the same project with different connection strings, I'm using EF Core Power Tools, but this tool it's generating a file config for whole project, worth noting that I'm working with Database First and separeting the entities from dbcontext in another class library project.

[image: DataAccess Layer]

[image: Entities Layer]

Comment: Put each model in a separate namespace so you can access each model by a different path name.  The filenames are just names and can be anything.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have tried that but the tool rewrite the file efpt.config.json and references to the new context

Comment: Make each model a different class project so you have separate config files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign a unique name to the config file according to the pattern described here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering#using-multiple-dbcontexts-in-the-same-project

Comment: Do I need another configuration? Because the tool gets the settings from efpt.config.json by default, it doesn't recognize the other configuration files

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I upgraded to the lastest version and it works. Thanks!